# Xamarin Forms ContentPage background image tiling

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im trying to set the ContentsPage BackgroundImage but on large screened devices the image keeps tiling.

Does anyone here know how to stop images from tiling?

**EDITED**

Here is an image of whats happening on iPads.

[image]

This is what it looks like on a phone:

[image]

MainPage.cs

```
namespace Application.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        RegisterDevice registerDevice;
        MenuAnimations menuAnimations;

        private double width;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            registerDevice = new RegisterDevice();
            menuAnimations = new MenuAnimations();

            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
            {
                Icon = "menuBtn.png",
                Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary
            });
        }

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
              BackgroundImage = "bg_portrait.png";
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Application.Views.MainPage">
  <ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Add screenshot, please.

Comment: I have added in a screenshot of the iPad.

Comment: Add `XAML` code, please. And how it should looks(screen from smaller device). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In respect that `BackgroundImage` property is of type `string` I'm not able to use properties of `<Image>`, `Aspect` for instance. So I would better do it in `XAML`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.Page1">
  <ContentView>
    <Image Source="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajyCo.png"
           Aspect="AspectFill"/>
  </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: That seems to work but I was planning on using a StackLayout to hold my components and whatnot. How do i overlay the stack layout over the image? Would I have to use a AbsoluteLayout or something?

Comment: Just use `Grid` instead of `ContentView` and put `Stack` inside `Grid`, should work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how to set background from local(resources)? I want to build in Android, iOs, and Windows.

Comment: @WStar, you might want to check official [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)