# How to set background image of ContentPage in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to set a background image on my Xamarin app.
I saw already [Xamarin Forms ContentPage background image tiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524529/xamarin-forms-contentpage-background-image-tiling) article.
At that code, has set a background image from the URL.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.Page1">
  <ContentView>
    <Image Source="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajyCo.png"
           Aspect="AspectFill"/>
  </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

I want to set from local Resources. So I have modified the XAML file like the following code. But It doesn't work. How to should I fix the following code.

I want to set the background image via only the XAML file. not via C# code.

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.Page1">
  <ContentView>
    <Image Source="Image/background.png"
           Aspect="AspectFill"/>
  </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

This is my Xamarin solution structure.

[image]

I want to build my app on Android, iOS, and Windows.
Please let me know in detail because I am a beginner at Xamarin.

Best regards.

Comment: If I am correct, your problem is that you are trying to set the image that is on the shared code but the application is looking in the platform project. For example Android will look to the background.png in the Drawable folder

Comment: I've copied `background.png` to the drawable folder and tried again, but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: please read the docs on using images in Forms - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1):

According to xamarin document:

> Image files can be added to each application project and referenced
> from Xamarin.Forms shared code. This method of distributing images is
> required when images are platform-specific, such as when using
> different resolutions on different platforms, or slightly different
> designs.

And on andriod.Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action: AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi).
see the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows